# Why is the following set not a Perfect Set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I learned about perfect set, which is a closed set whose all elements are limit points.

So, my Teaching Assistants gave me some examples.

$\mathbb{R}, [0, 1], \mbox{Cantor set}$ are examples of perfect set.

$\{0\}, \{-1\}\cup[0,\infty)$ are not perfect set because they have isolated points.

$\displaystyle\left\{1, \frac12, \frac13, \cdots \right\}$ is not perfect set because limit point, which is $0$, is not an element of the set.

$\displaystyle\left\{1, \frac12, \frac13, \cdots \right\}\cup\{0\}$ is not perfect set as well.

I don't understand why the last set is not perfect set.

Can someone explain? thank you very much.

Comment: A necessary condition for perfect-ness is that the set is uncountable (or empty).

Comment: Yes, my mistake is that I am only focusing on the points around zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to read the definition of perfect set again. The last set is not perfect sets because $1, \frac{1}{2}, \ldots $ are not limit points. It contradicts with the definition of perfect set.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_set

Comment: Ah!!! before arriving around zero, the numbers are isolated points. Thank you. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Look for isolated points.

Comment: Thank you for answer :) I understood!